# Problem saving data into Polymorphic relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphic-associations, relation

I have some doubts on polymorphic relationship.
I have the schema attached where document can be connected to sectors if 'senderable_type' is Sector or, to addresses if is Address.
Base on value get from a form, I know if it is connected to a Sector or to an Address, getting its ID.
But...how to do this? Can you help me please?
Each document can be linked to one sector or to one address. Is it possible to use Polymorphic for this use?

These are my relationships on models:

```
//Document.php
public function documentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

//Sector.php
public function documents()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Document::class, 'senderable');
    }

//Address.php
public function documents()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Document::class, 'senderable');
    }
```

And this is the code of my store function in my controller:

```
if (is_null($request->get('sender_id'))) {
                $type = "App\Sector";
                $sender_id = $request->get("sector_id");
            } else {
                $type = "App\Address";
                $sender_id = $request->get("sender_id");
            }

            $documento = Document::create(
                [
                    'company_id' => $request->get("company_id") ?? Auth::user()->company_id,
                    'date' => Carbon::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $request->get("date")),
                    'type' => $request->get("origin"),
                    'subject' => $request->get("subject"),
                    'senderable_type' => $type,
                    'senderable_id' => $sender_id,
                    'protocol_number' => '0',
                    'protocol_date' => Carbon::now(),
                    'is_reserved' => false,
                    'created_user_id' => Auth::id(),
                ]
            );
```

Actually I check if it is related to a Sector or to an Address and manually save in the DB. I don't know if it is the best way...

[image]

Comment: What you have seems like it should work. Which part of it specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: I don't know how to save it using polymorphic functions....I have already addresses and sectors, I would to create a document related to one of these model...

Comment: Please can you show the relationships you've set up in your models, the form you have and the controller code.

Comment: @Rwd I edit my post with relationships

Comment: What about the form and controller(s)?

Comment: @Rwd added function too